# Django-Summernote editor not showing in Admin

Tags: python, django, admin, summernote

I have a Django app for post-writing. I've integrated django-summernote to the app but I came across a issue that the django summernote widgets is not showing in admin panel. It is working fine and smooth in my template but its not showing in admin panel. Kindly help me out.

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS += ('django_summernote', ) 
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'

SUMMERNOTE_CONFIG = {
    'iframe': False,
    "jquery": "summernoteJQuery",

    'summernote': {

        'width': '100%'
    }
}

SUMMERNOTE_THEME = 'bs3'
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post, Comment

from django_summernote.admin import SummernoteModelAdmin


class PostAdmin(SummernoteModelAdmin):
    summernote_fields = ('text',)

admin.site.register(Post,PostAdmin)
admin.site.register(Comment)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import include
# ...
urlpatterns = [
...
path('summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls')),
...
] 
...
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                      document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

[screenshotAdminPanel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yRla.png)

[After 'Iframe = True'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYnzk.png)

Comment: Can you show your Post models here? Which field you wanted to be enabled for summernote?? That field has to be a TextField.

Comment: It is "text = models.TextField(verbose_name ="Blog Content",)  "

Comment: In your screenshot I did not see any field called text.

Comment: Thats a verbose_name, should I use that field name as parameter in "summernote_fields"

Comment: Yes, Use Direct field name

Comment: After editing it and setting as "summernote_fields = ('Blog Content',)" nothing happened. The normal text field appeared which is better from the previous one but I want that text field should be a summernote field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using Bootstrap or an external CSS framework in your Django admin panel, you have to set `'iframe': True` in your `SUMMERNOTE_CONFIG`. Otherwise, if you are using Bootstrap or an external CSS framework, set it to `False`. Here's the corrected grammar and Markdown:

```
# Using SummernoteWidget - iframe mode, default
'iframe': True,

# Or, you can set it to `False` to use SummernoteInplaceWidget by default - no iframe mode
# In this case, you have to load Bootstrap/jQuery sources and dependencies manually.
# Use this when you're already using Bootstrap/jQuery based themes.
'iframe': False,
```

Check the documentation for more details: [django-summernote GitHub](https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote?tab=readme-ov-file#options).

Comment: I have added the screenshot after updating "'iframe': True," but nothing happened the space for text area got bigger and also now it is not showing in template.

Comment: what had happened in  second screenshot

Comment: Ohh that was just because of a code snippet which I thought can be a fix for this problem.